# What is the opposite of height?

Tags: terminology

Considering that *depth* denotes the distance below sea-level to a point on an object located below sea level, and considering that *height* denotes the distance to some point above the surface of the earth as measured from a point on surface of the earth, it seems there ought to be a term that denotes the distance to some point below the surface of the earth as measured from a point on the surface of the earth.

For example, suppose someone dug a mine shaft down into the earth from an elevated point, but not so far down that it descends below sea-level; what term ought we use to denote the points below the surface of the earth?

Comment: This may be more suitable for posting at [Earth Science](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Better still... http://english.stackexchange.com/ since it contains information on language and usage

Comment: @DanPatterson: I think if it's about *GIS* language/usage, it's better off here -- same reasoning as for GIS programming and GIS data sets being here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are limiting the applicability of 'depth'. You say

> depth denotes the distance below sea-level to a point on an object
>   located below sea level

This isn't strictly correct. Depth is usually used for all negative distances from any surface, not just below sea level.

In all industries and applications that I have worked with, depth is used to indicate the distance below the reference surface.

Depth is the nomenclature used in:

- The Oil & Gas industry [example](http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_crd_welldep_s1_a.htm)
- The location of [Earthquakes](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/atom.php)
- Natural resources, especially [Groundwater](http://pubs.usgs.gov/sir/2008/5059/section4.html) and [Minerals](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00734672#page-1)

So 'Depth' is the word that you should use, and most people, in all kinds of industries and fields will understand you.

Answer (score 2):

The term height can be used for both above and below ground measurements.  My definition of height includes the vertical distance from the origin of measurement--this can be either + or -.  For example, if I am standing at the bottom of a mineshaft and use my laser range finder to determine the height to the surface, the measurement may be 1000 m.  Alternatively, if I am standing at the top of the mine shaft and measure the vertical distance to the bottom, the height would be -1000 m.

Answer (score 1):

Since GIS is a very multidisciplinary subject, there are always going to be many differences in terminology for the same basic concept. Which is "correct" depends on the specific context.

Some synonyms for *height*: elevation, rise, altitude, ascent, relief, hypsography, orography.

Some synonyms for *"opposite of height"*: depth, fall, invert, descent, bathymetry.

You can always use the same term and simply apply positive values for *up* and negative values for *down*.